# Automatically update Android App on Tablet (i.e. without Market!)

Tags: java, android, installation

I've written an Android App which is primarily targeted to Android Tablets without the Market installed, which means the user cannot easily update the App. My idea is to download the apk file and do whatever the MArket is doing with the apk file.

As the app is preinstalled on the Tablets there is no restriction in Permissions, but the device must not to be rooted.

Comment: Does anyone know how the Market is installing the apk-file after downloading it? If the market does not use any special permissions only available to Google/the vendor it should be possible to use exactly this functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems the following code allows the user to install the apk after detecting a new version and downloading the apk file:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

well i think that you just can do something like these. Verify version if version is lower app don't run.

Comment: Well the application is to be sold and to satisfy the customer. Just displaying an Webview with an download link instead of starting the app is not really what I believe is user friendly. I'd like to have an user experience comparable to the Android Marked (which is unfortunately not open source).